# I just installed Garageband on my mac but I don't know if it charged my card

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, mac-appstore, charging, garageband

So, I wanted to use an app to edit some audio for a project. I have a mac but it does not have an in-built GB app, so when I looked for it online, it said that I had to pay $4.99. I did not want to buy the app for I let it be. But I was on App Store just now and it asked me to install the app (it did not say purchase), so I installed it. Now, how do I know if it was charged or did it download for free because I have a mac?

Comment: It depends on when you bought the Mac. Some purchases [past 3 or 4 years, not sure when it started] give the first registered owner free versions of GarageBand, Pages, Keynote etc. Usually the way you know is that is says 'download' rather than 'buy', but it depends on whether you were signed in at the time.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to check this. Go into iTunes and click the Store tab. Once it has loaded, scroll to the very bottom of the page, and under Manage you will see a link to your Account. Click there and sign into your Apple ID if prompted, then under Purchase History click See All. This will give you a list of all the apps you have downloaded from the App Store, iTunes store, and other Apple services. Find GarageBand in the list, and if the price is labeled as $0.00, you will not be charged for the app. But if it is labeled otherwise, you will be charged for the app.